# how to append a new div between each img tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
    <div class="sample">
    <img src="images/i1.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/i2.jpg"/>
    <img src="images/i3.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

i want to append like this but class should be created and append dynamically using jquery:I tried but my logic is wrong so anyone help

```
        <div class="sample">
    <div class="new"> <img src="images/i1.jpg"/> </div>
    <div class="new"> <img src="images/i2.jpg"/> </div>
    <div class="new"> <img src="images/i3.jpg"/> </div>
    </div>

    $('img').each(function(){ 
var that = $(this);    
var v = document.createElement('div');
v.setAttribute('class','new');
$(v).append(that);
$('sample').append(v);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.sample img').wrap('<div class="new"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrap` method:

```
$('.sample img').wrap('<div clas="new"></div>');
```

Your code also works if you add `.` for the class selector:

```
$('sample').append(v);
// ^---
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6hYFc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="new">content</div>')
```

should be all you need